# Filtering Columns Based on String Value

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am pulling data set of parameters, listed in rows. These parameters are associated via a Source Sequence. One of the rows within a given sequence has a string value, only listed for a single row. I'm trying to filter this result and list the string value for each row based on the sequence instead of having a single row an the remaining roles listing as null. Can this be done in SSRS report side?

example: the batch string is embedded in this concatenation. I don't want to filter out diameter and hardness as well, so I can't necessary filter only on batch.

```
PAT_ID     ME      STRING_VALUE      NUM_Value  Source_CD_Sequence
Diameter   CDC     Null               9.83            0
Hardness   CDC     Null               17.3            0
ID_Tablet  CDC    20190117-7h40m/1/1  Null            0

SELECT
  PVXMEDE.PAT_ID,
  PVXMEDE.ME,
  PVXMEDE.STRING_VALUE,
  PVXMEDE.NUM_VALUE,
  PVXMEDE.SOURCE_CD_SEQUENCE,
  PVXMEDE.SOURCE_EXECUTION_ID
FROM
  PVXMEDE
   FULL OUTER JOIN PVXMIDE ON (PVXMEDE.SOURCE_EXECUTION_ID=PVXMIDE.SOURCE_EXECUTION_ID AND PVXMEDE.SOURCE_CD_SEQUENCE=PVXMIDE.SOURCE_CD_SEQUENCE AND PVXMEDE.STRING_VALUE=PVXMIDE.STRING_VALUE AND PVXMEDE.DATE_LOCAL=PVXMIDE.DATE_LOCAL)
   RIGHT JOIN PVXME ON (PVXME.ME=PVXMEDE.ME)
   AND PVXMEDE.PAT_ID IN ('THICKNESS', 'WEIGHT', 'DIAMETER', 'HARDNESS', 'ID_TABLET')
Where
PVXME.CX_STRING_4 = '20190117-7h40m'
```

Expected filtering:

```
PAT_ID     ME      STRING_VALUE      NUM_Value  Source_CD_Sequence
Diameter   CDC    20190117-7h40m/1/1  9.83            0
Hardness   CDC    20190117-7h40m/1/1  17.3            0
ID_Tablet  CDC    20190117-7h40m/1/1  Null            0
```

Comment: can you show desired result please? rather than describing it??

Comment: @Harry.  The desired result i'm looking for is to probagate string_value 20190117-7h40m/1/1 for Diameter and Hardness, removing the Null. these are figures that associate with that string.

Comment: < PAT_ID     ME      STRING_VALUE        Value  Source_CD_Sequence >
< Diameter   CDC    20190117-7h40m/1/1  9.83             0>
< Hardness   CDC   20190117-7h40m/1/1  17.3             0 >
< ID_Tablet  CDC    20190117-7h40m/1/1  Null             0 >

Comment: is it possible to have more than one "String_Value" in your result set?

Comment: Yes, there is more than one string value in the set.  There could be several sets of string values. In this case there will be 20190117-7h40m/1/2 and 20190117-7h40m/1/3 usually up until 10 then it resets 20190117-7h40m/2/1 etc.... Per  sequence group. In that sequence group there are diameter, Hardness, Thickness, Weight.  The common denominator is the batch, with is the beginning part. (20190117-7h40m)

Comment: so there needs to be something in the dataset that determines a "set". So i know which string to use to replace the null for that set.. makes sense?

Comment: @Harry. Within the dataset, there is a Sequence. Every sequence group will have a ID_TABLET string to associate with the group. This ID_TABLET String ties back to the batch. For every sequence, If String is null then replace null with ID_TABLET string value. Is my thinking correct?  Is this better suited for SSRS to handle?  I think I'm understanding your point.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished using CTE tables - Just one way of doing it.

what you could do is select distinct sequence and string value where string value is not null into a cte or into a temp table.. then when you have your final dataset, join the dataset back to the temp table or cte on the sequence number.. and fill in the nulls with the string value. makes sense?

something like this

```
if OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#string_values') is not null
drop table #string_values

;with mycte as ( -- this is the distinct set of sequence and associated string values that are not null
select 1 as sequence , '20190117-7h40m/1/1' as string_value
union all
select 3 as sequence , '20190117-7h40m/2/1' as string_value
union all
select 4 as sequence , '20190117-7h40m/3/1' as string_value
)

select * -- putting everything into a temp table
into 
#string_values

from mycte

-- this is your data set please note that the sequence has been included
;with my_dataset as (
select 'Diameter' as PAT_ID , 'CDC' as ME, null as STRING_VALUE , 9.83 as NUM_value, 0 as  Source_CD_Sequence, 1 as sequence
 union all
 select   'Hardness' as PAT_ID , 'CDC' as ME, null as STRING_VALUE , 17.3 as NUM_value, 0 as  Source_CD_Sequence     , 1 as sequence
 union all
  select   'Hardness' as PAT_ID , 'CDC' as ME, '20190117-7h40m/3/1' as STRING_VALUE , null as NUM_value, 0 as  Source_CD_Sequence     , 1 as sequence


  )

  Select 
  my_dataset.PAT_ID
  ,my_dataset.ME
  ,isnull(my_dataset.STRING_VALUE,string_val.string_value) as STRING_VALUE
  ,my_dataset.NUM_value
  ,my_dataset.Source_CD_Sequence

   from my_dataset

  inner join #string_values string_val
    on string_val.sequence = my_dataset.sequence
```